# How to align vertically by right border?

Tags: vertical-alignment, plain-tex

Consider this example:

```
\hsize.1in \noindent \parfillskip=0pt \leftskip=0pt plus 1fil \hfuzz=2em hello world
\bye
```

The result is:

[image: result of example]

The expected result is:

[image]

Why the example does not produce the expected result and how should it be modified?

Comment: Why do you expect the second result? I'd expect exactly what you get!

Comment: @JosephWright: s/expected/desired/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two overfull boxes: "hello" and "world" after paragraph breaking is done. These boxes are re-calculated to the width .1in in your example and they are  not reported because `\hfuzz=2em`. They are placed to the same position as if `\hfuzz=0pt`. And overfull boxes are lapped right, of course.

If you need lapped left the lines broken at each word space in the paragraph, you can try:

```
\hsize=0pt \noindent \parfillskip=0pt 
\leftskip=0pt plus 1fil minus10em            
hello world
\bye
```

The problem of both solutions (yours and my) is that the total width of the result (the measure of the the widest box) is not calculated. So you need to shift this result right by `\moveright something\vbox{...}` and the "something" measure must be calculated (or estimated) by another way.

If you explicitly need to know the width of the result then you need to create a macro which separates the text to the words and measures the widest word.

Answer (score 1):

The following code makes use of `\centering` , `\justify`, and `flushright` to align text in the corresponding ways. The problem proposed is suited to make use of `\begin{flushright} text \end{flushright}`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e} %for use of \justify 

\begin{document}

Justified text:    
\justify
Some words to be used. Some words to be used. Some words to be used. Some words to be used. Some words to be used.
Some words to be used. Some words to be used. Some words to be used. Some words to be used. Some words to be used. 
Some words to be used. Some words to be used. Some words to be used. Some words to be used. Some words to be used. 
Some words to be used.

Flush right text:
\begin{flushright}
Some words to be used. Some words to be used. Some words to be used. Some words to be used. Some words to be used. 
Some words to be used. Some words to be used. Some words to be used. Some words to be used. Some words to be used. 
Some words to be used. Some words to be used. Some words to be used. Some words to be used. Some words to be used.
Some words to be used.
\end{flushright}

Centered text:
\centering
Some words to be used. Some words to be used. Some words to be used. Some words to be used. Some words to be used. 
Some words to be used. Some words to be used. Some words to be used. Some words to be used. Some words to be used. 
Some words to be used. Some words to be used. Some words to be used. Some words to be used. Some words to be used. 
Some words to be used.

\end{document}
```

Comment: The question is about plain/TeX core!